# create master list of unique keywords

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list ('a') in python that is my original list. I have a second list ('b'). I want to compare list 'a' and 'b' and create a new list ('c') that I want to take action on. List 'c' should only contain unique values from b that are not in a. (See examples below.)

**Original list:**
a = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']

**New list has a duplicate entry from 'a' ('pear'):** b = ['pear', 'banana', 'grape']

**Desired final output list with new items only:** 
c = ['banana', 'grape']

Lastly, when I'm done, I want to update my original list so that it contains everything: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear','banana', 'grape']

Comment: Perhaps use `set`s instead?

Comment: I suggest looking into [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 0):

This may do the needful:

```
c = [each for each in b if each not in a ]
```

To update the original list, a simple **extend** would do like:

```
 a.extend(c)
```

Comment: how would I do the final part of my request?: Lastly, when I'm done, I want to update my original list so that it contains everything: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear','banana', 'grape']

Comment: Updated the post. You may try now.